# i have added some new dependencies to my flutter project that was working fine and then deleted them and i keep facing this error when run my project

Tags: flutter, gradle

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 64 arm64 in debug mode...
: Error: Error when reading '../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/test_api-0.4.16/lib/src/expect/expect.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.

export 'src/expect/expect.dart' show expect, expectLater, fail;
^

: Error: Error when reading '../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/test_api-0.4.16/lib/src/expect/expect.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.

import 'expect.dart';
^

: Error: Error when reading '../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/test_api-0.4.16/lib/src/expect/expect.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.

export 'src/expect/expect.dart' show ErrorFormatter;

^
: Error: Error when reading '../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/test_api-0.4.16/lib/src/expect/expect.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.

import 'expect.dart';

```
   ^
```

: Error: Error when reading '../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/test_api-0.4.16/lib/src/expect/expect.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.

import 'expect.dart';
^

: Error: Error when reading '../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/test_api-0.4.16/lib/src/expect/expect.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.

import 'expect.dart';
^

/C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/_goldens_io.dart:120:7: Error: The method 'fail' isn't defined for the class 'LocalFileComparator'.

- 'LocalFileComparator' is from 'package:flutter_test/src/_goldens_io.dart' ('/C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/_goldens_io.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'fail'.
  fail(
  ^^^^
  /C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/binding.dart:1202:7: Error: The method 'fail' isn't defined for the class 'AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding'.
- 'AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding' is from 'package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart' ('/C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/binding.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'fail'.
  fail(
  ^^^^
  /C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/binding.dart:1208:6: Error: A value of type 'bool?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't.
  }());

  ^
  /C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/binding.dart:1853:7: Error: The method 'fail' isn't defined for the class 'LiveTestWidgetsFlutterBinding'.
- 'LiveTestWidgetsFlutterBinding' is from 'package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart' ('/C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/binding.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'fail'.
  fail(
  ^^^^
  /C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/binding.dart:1859:6: Error: A value of type 'bool?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't.
  }());
  ^
  /C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/widget_tester.dart:460:16: Error: Method not found: 'expect'.
  test_package.expect(actual, matcher, reason: reason, skip: skip);
  ^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/widget_tester.dart:477:16: Error: Method not found: 'expect'.
  test_package.expect(actual, matcher, reason: reason);
  ^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/widget_tester.dart:497:23: Error: Method not found: 'expectLater'.
  return test_package.expectLater(actual, matcher, reason: reason, skip: skip)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/widget_tester.dart:663:22: Error: Method not found: 'fail'.
  test_package.fail(
  ^^^^
  : Error: The method 'expect' isn't defined for the class 'AsyncMatcher'.
- 'AsyncMatcher' is from 'package:test_api/src/expect/async_matcher.dart' ('../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/test_api-0.4.16/lib/src/expect/async_matcher.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'expect'.

  expect(result,
  ^^^^^^
  : Error: The method 'fail' isn't defined for the class 'AsyncMatcher'.
- 'AsyncMatcher' is from 'package:test_api/src/expect/async_matcher.dart' ('../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/test_api-0.4.16/lib/src/expect/async_matcher.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'fail'.
  fail(formatFailure(this, item, realResult as String));
  ^^^^
  : Error: The method 'formatFailure' isn't defined for the class 'AsyncMatcher'.
- 'AsyncMatcher' is from 'package:test_api/src/expect/async_matcher.dart' ('../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/test_api-0.4.16/lib/src/expect/async_matcher.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'formatFailure'.
  fail(formatFailure(this, item, realResult as String));
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  : Error: The method 'fail' isn't defined for the class '_DoesNotComplete'.
- '_DoesNotComplete' is from 'package:test_api/src/expect/future_matchers.dart' ('../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/test_api-0.4.16/lib/src/expect/future_matchers.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'fail'.
  fail('Future was not expected to complete but completed with a value of '

  ```
  ^^^^
  ```

: Error: The method 'expect' isn't defined for the class '_DoesNotComplete'.

- '_DoesNotComplete' is from 'package:test_api/src/expect/future_matchers.dart' ('../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/test_api-0.4.16/lib/src/expect/future_matchers.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'expect'.
  expect(pumpEventQueue(), completes);

  ^^^^^^
  : Error: Method not found: 'expect'.
  expect(pumpEventQueue(), completes);
  ^^^^^^

: Error: Type 'OperatingSystem' not found.
final OperatingSystem os;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: Undefined name 'OperatingSystem'.
{this.os = OperatingSystem.none, this.inGoogle = false}) {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

: Error: 'OperatingSystem' isn't a type.
final OperatingSystem os;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

: Error: The getter 'OperatingSystem' isn't defined for the class 'SuitePlatform'.

- 'SuitePlatform' is from 'package:test_api/src/backend/suite_platform.dart' ('../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/test_api-0.4.16/lib/src/backend/suite_platform.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'OperatingSystem'.
  if (runtime.isBrowser && os != OperatingSystem.none) {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  : Error: Undefined name 'OperatingSystem'.
  os: OperatingSystem.find(map['os'] as String),
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  : Error: Undefined name 'OperatingSystem'.
  for (var os in OperatingSystem.all) os.identifier,
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1157
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

i tried flutter clean and flutter pub get and then created a new project and added it to fire base as anew project
i deleted pubspec.loc and flutter pub get and the same problem please help

Answer (score 0):

If you remove some dependencies,
then

> delete the pubspec.lock file.
> then Run pub get again.
> then restart with clean cache.
> then run the project.

Answer (score 0):

- delete the `pubspec.lock` file
- run the `flutter clean` command
- run the `flutter pub get` command
- run the project again

This should fix the issue as it gets dependencies with a clean project cache.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved when i update flutter to 3.10.0 then run flutter run - v after that a new problem with gradle appeared i deleted my gradle cash from c/:user/.gradle/cash and then run ./gradlew build delete